# regex to match on username of email address

Tags: regex

I'm looking for some help on a regular expression. I'd like a match to be where the username (i.e. everything before the @ sign) of an email address includes the word **hello** and also the letter **a**. So, example:

```
// matches
ahello@outlook.com
helloa@yahoo.com

// does not match
hello@gmail.com
```

I'm still pretty new to regex craft, therefore pointers and explanations appreciated.

Comment: Maybe read [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)?

Comment: so far I was trying `^.*?(?=@)` to match from the start of the string, any character 0 or more times until the next char was @ to initially get anything before the @ sign. My plan was to tweak this to get what I want, but this doesnt seem to work, hence why I'm stuck and in need of pointers.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions#emails-example) is a pretty good resource I find myself looking up over and over. The specific part I linked to discusses email address parsing. It won't do exactly what you want, but I recommend taking a look at that and coming back with any changes you've made.

Comment: @CameronGagnon that is a good resource. noted and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from language, you can use positive lookaheads (hopefully) to assert that there are both occurrences of **hello** and **a** in username part:

```
(?=[^@]*hello)(?=[^@]*a).+
```

What it matches:

```
ahello@outlook.com
helloa@yahoo.com
myhellonamea@gmail.com
...
```

Comment: this is excellent, i've plugged into regex101 for an explanation of each element also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're pretty sure that your email address will consist only of optional `a` and `hello` then use this query:

```
^(a(hello)@|(hello)a@)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZ9uG8/2) with explanation

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful although i'd like a match on something like helloabc@yahoo.com, therefore I was not explicit enough in my question

Comment: Ok, no worries. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just another option for anyone that comes across this in the future. If you'd like to match a different set of characters other than `a` then replace the `a` in the regex with the character(s) desired.

`(a.*)@|(.*a.*)@`

```
abchello@gmail.com # matches abchello in group 
helloabc@gmail.com # matches helloabc
hello@gmail.com    # no match
bhello@gmail.com   # no match
hellob@gmail.com   # no match
```